# How to sort value from an array into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an array that looks as follow:

```
 {'peak_heights': array([ 276.,  498.,  342.,  885.,  548.,  340., 1462.,  383.,  982.,
           1482., 1661.,  730., 1211., 1726., 1516., 1794.,  851., 1744.,
           1341., 1714., 1475., 1756., 1149., 1803.,  731., 1571., 1481.,
           1992.,  742., 1477.,  246., 1055.,  378.,  485.,  562.,  428.,
           1132.,  676., 1202., 1042., 1153.,  421., 1136.,  436., 1114.,
            219., 1095.,  871.,  543.,  778.,  712., 1231.,  616., 1491.,
            647.,  464., 1164., 1344., 1043.,  598., 1024.,  951.,  655.,
           1378.,  250.,  986.,  965.,  363.,  947.,  475.,  381.,  240.,
            585.,  626.,  349.,  760.,  439.,  241.,  439.,  352.,  980.,
            297.,  336., 1054.,  448., 1636.,  244., 1079., 2746.,  777.,
           1007.,  745., 1918.,  519., 2024., 1391.,  712., 1933.,  234.,
           1466., 1263., 1239., 1746.,  830.,  371.,  648.,  277., 1567.,
            992.,  572.,  661.,  465.,  658.,  473.,  460.,  450.,  631.,
            256.,  515.,  311.,  586.,  508.,  226.,  870.,  775.,  285.,
            718.,  850.,  686.,  933.,  240.,  724.,  206.,  731.,  310.,
            857.,  308.,  673.,  280.,  205.,  664.,  202.,  521.,  564.,
            806.,  712.,  827.,  852.,  210.,  438.,  335.,  603.,  897.,
            860., 1069., 1460.,  216.,  880.,  486., 1502., 1189.,  896.,
           1509.,  280., 1055., 1269.,  367.,  733.,  203.,  653.,  952.,
            318.,  583.,  648.,  639.,  778.,  778.,  793., 1023.,  762.,
            735.,  899.,  475.,  240.,  302.,  800.,  215.,  959.,  270.,
            641.,  801.,  290.,  880.,  797.,  282.,  821.,  793.,  637.,
            600.,  240.,  270.,  449.,  475.,  878.,  306.,  932.,  956.,
            877.,  954.,  660.,  961.,  947.,  978., 1178.,  685.,  509.,
            984.,  289.,  806.,  888.,  851.,  727.,  908.,  759.,  931.,
            666.,  772.,  671.,  421.,  519.,  724.,  202.,  682.,  513.,
            203.,  722.,  279.,  368.,  262.,  391.,  261.,  224.,  753.,
            271.,  898., 1072.,  697.,  378.,  971.,  710.,  903.,  739.,
            209., 1249.,  330., 1473.,  706.,  722.,  776.,  854., 1363.,
            796.,  284.,  542.,  551.,  219.,  570.,  665.,  220.,  506.,
            848.,  852.,  704.,  408.,  389.,  427.,  750.,  419.,  930.,
           1140., 1029.,  930.,  841.,  834.,  627., 1011.,  950., 1010.,
            889.,  607.,  349.,  270.,  742.,  317.,  619.,  821.,  758.,
            484.,  320., 1100.,  931.,  363.,  800.,  558.,  785.,  356.,
            325.,  509.,  318.,  433.,  626.,  582.,  890.,  983.,  591.,
            919.,  227.,  870.,  324.,  809.,  640.,  932.,  816.,  448.,
            314.,  513.,  848.,  722., 1336., 1050., 1099.,  235.,  923.,
            314., 1139., 1384.,  722.,  774.,  916.,  686.,  255.,  692.,
            867.,  220.,  566.,  303.,  617., 1311.,  884., 1038.,  499.,
            265., 1057.,  717.,  974.,  860.,  253., 1112., 1068.])}
```

For the array I want to create a dataframe that has two columns, one is the 'odd' values and one is the 'even' values in the array. So the first column would have 276, 342,548,1462,982.... and the second would have 498,885,340,383....

Does anyone know a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To pair data from one list use `zip(x[::2], x[1::2])`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'peak_heights': np.arange(10)}
print(data)  # {'peak_heights': array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(data['peak_heights'][::2], data['peak_heights'][1::2]),
                  columns=['a', 'b'])
print(df)
```

```
   a  b
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```